# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PROJECT_ NAME.wsgi' Heroku

Tags: heroku

I would like to get some ideas about the error that I am getting. I have searched now but I couldn't get anything. I checked other resources to compare the my Procfile, and it seems that I have the correct format.

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn animals.wsgi:application --log-file - --log-level debug
```

Error I am getting:

```
2018-01-27T10:34:15.354613+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-27 10:34:15 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.355559+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-27 10:34:15 +0000] [4] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.361083+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-27 10:34:15 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.367431+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'animals.wsgi'
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.354290+00:00 app[web.1]:   keyfile: None
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.354294+00:00 app[web.1]:   cert_reqs: 0
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.354299+00:00 app[web.1]:   do_handshake_on_connect: False
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.367419+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.367424+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.354287+00:00 app[web.1]:   proxy_protocol: False
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.367425+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.367413+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.354300+00:00 app[web.1]:   ciphers: TLSv1
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.355880+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-27 10:34:15 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.367412+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.367601+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-27 10:34:15 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.410294+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-27 10:34:15 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
    2018-01-27T10:34:15.410106+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-27 10:34:15 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had the same issue. This solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616586/gunicorn-django-importerror-no-module-named-application-wsgi

Answer (score 1):

Extending answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616586/gunicorn-django-importerror-no-module-named-application-wsgi) I tried my WSGI path to `gunicorn myproject.myproject.wsgi:application --log-file -`and yes error changed now it says `ImportError: No module named myproject.settings`. To solve this I changed my wsgi file.

FROM:

`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')`

TO:

`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.myproject.settings')`

It woked like a charm for me!

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same error by making the following changes, I was able to resolve it.

1. The `Procfile` should be in the `myproject` directory along with **manage.py** and **.git** but not in `myproject/myproject`.

[image]

2. The `Procfile` should have this code `web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi`
3. `gunicorn` package should be mentioned in the `requirements.txt` file.