# ModuleNotFound error trying to open Django app in Heroku- issue with gunicorn setup?

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

I've been building my first Django project (just running it locally so far using runserver), and I'm taking the steps to host it on Heroku, adding gunicorn. The build succeeds, but when I try to open the app, **the Heroku logs show an exception in worker process**:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.wsgi'
```

Originally my Procfile had this:

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi
```

When I would try that gunicorn command locally, it would work from within the family-django/mysite directory, but when I tried from the root directory (family-django), it would give me the same 'no module named mysite.wsgi' error. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616586/gunicorn-django-importerror-no-module-named-application-wsgi), Heroku's going to try from the root directory, so I updated my Procfile as follows, to tell it to run from the mysite directory instead:

```
web: gunicorn --chdir mysite mysite.wsgi
```

This new gunicorn command does work locally when run from the root directory (family-django), hooray!! That must be the fix I need. **BUT: after updating the Procfile in Heroku and trying to open the app again, it still fails with that 'no module named mysite.wsgi' error pasted above.** So there's some other tweak that Heroku needs for this to run there.

My Django project structure is like this:

```
family-django
|-mysite 
| |-familytree
| |-myauth
| |-mysite
|   |-asgi.py
|   |-settings.py
|   |-urls.py
|   |-wsgi.py
|-Procfile
|-requirements.txt
```

wsgi.py and asgi.py were both created at the start of the project. (Not sure if it's wrong to have both?). wsgi.py has:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

settings.py has the following info for INSTALLED_APPS and WSGI_APPLICATION:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'familytree.apps.FamilytreeConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    "myauth",
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'
```

Now that I'd like to get this up on Heroku, they recommend gunicorn, so I've added a requirements.txt:

```
django
django-heroku
gunicorn
```

Procfile has:

```
web: gunicorn --chdir mysite mysite.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#----------------------------Install packages---------------------------- 
 1)pip install django-heroku
 2)pip install whitenoise

#-----------------------------setting.py----------------------------------#
1)INSTALLED_APPS = [
...,
'django_heroku',
]

2)MIDDLEWARE = [
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

 ]

3)STATICFILES_STORAGE = 
 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

4)STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)


django_heroku.settings(locals())

#-----------------------urls.py---------------------------------------#
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
 ...,
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

 #------------------Procfile create in Root DIR-----------------#
  paste in  (web: gunicorn projectname.wsgi)

 #--------------create requirements.txt---------------------------#

 pip freeze > requirements.txt

 # runtime.txt  create in Root DIR
 paste in (your python version for ex.python-3.8.5)

 #---------then commands in terminal-------------------------#

 heroku login
 heroku create YOUR_APP_NAME

 ##for Clone the repository.......
 git init
 heroku git:clone -a YOUR_APP_NAME

 ## for Deploy your changes......
 git init
 git add .
 git commit - m "initial"
 git push heroku master

 ## then

 heroku run python manage.py migrate
 heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: Weird! Yes the difference turned out to be adding whitenoise! I hadn't realized that Heroku needs it in order to support static assets: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
That initial error message wouldn't have made me think of going in that direction, thanks for the nudge!